# SqlFileStream - Which FileOption and allocation size?

Tags: c#, async-await, filestream, sqlfilestream

I am using the SqlFileStream and when constructing the object I am not sure which FileOptions and allocation size to use. I got this from another article but it did not explain why. Can somone help explain or give me a recommendation?

thanks!

```
using (var destination = new SqlFileStream(serverPathName, serverTxnContext, FileAccess.Write, FileOptions.Asynchronous, 4096))
{
    await file.CopyToAsync(destination);
}
```

Comment: have you thought about trying a `Google Search` on the Following
`C# MSDN SqlFileStream`

Comment: yes i did however it did not answer my questions.

Comment: try this and maybe you it will shed some light https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674879.aspx also you understand what the 4096 part is in regards to size / chunks..? also this link explains what all the different methods and property's etc ... do https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: 4096 - i don't have a good grip on it quite yet

Comment: what's not to understand.. I would suggest you read up of how to write files in chunks then you will see what that number represents.. and like I have stated in the previous comment.. read the documentation it's right there in front of you. take the time to read it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears like you are trying to copy this file asynchronously, you probably want `FileOptions.Asynchronous`. This the most responsive way to access your file, because you aren't bound to one thread. `FileOptions.RandomAccess` and `FileOptions.SequentialScan` both use caching the access the file however `FileOptions.SequentialScan` isn't guaranteed to cache optimally. Like the name implies, the large difference is how the access the file either randomly or sequentially. The `WriteThrough` just skips the cache and goes directly to the file which would be faster but riskier.

Allocation size is just the block size on the drive. If you pass `0` it would use the default size, which for an NTFS formatted drive would be 4KB. `4096` turns out to be 4KB so the person here is just making sure the block size is 4KB.

Comment: You can find more details about AllocationSize here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030171/ntcreatefile-allocationsize   (SqlFileStream calls NtCreateFile internally). Also, for example, how does FAT file system driver use it: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/allocsup.c

Comment: "The WriteThrough just skips the cache and goes directly to the file which would be faster but riskier." - it would be the other way around.